# How to correct spatial autocorrelation with glmmTMB when there are several observations on sites?

Tags: mixed-model, autocorrelation, spatial, ecology, glmmtmb

I have a large dataset of several species' activity parameters during nights and I want to account for spatial autocorrelation (tests and graphs show that my models suffer from it). However, I cannot find a proper way to do it (I have already tested adding latitude and longitude in my models).

My models are built that way (all covariates are scaled) : *Parameter ~ Landuse covariates + Weather covariates + Other covariates + (1|site), weight = total_activity, family= "gaussian"*

The construction of my dataset is the following one :

- I have a lot of sites, monitored during at least one night, but many of them were monitored several nights (either consecutive nights or not),
- one line of my dataset corresponds to one night at one site.

I tried to add the following parameter to my models : `exp(pos + 0 | site)` with pos : `myTable$pos <- numFactor(myTable$Longitude_scaled, myTable$Latitude_scaled)`

But my models runned for more than an hour and I had to stop it (thus I don't even know if it would have work eventually). However, as I want to compute dredges on these models, I can't allow one single model to run for too much time (even if I use pdredge and clusters).

To conclude:

1. Is this the proper way to take into account spatial autocorrelation with glmmTMB ?
2. Should I write it : exp(pos + 0 |site) or exp(pos + 0 |group) with group always equal to "1" for example?
3. Is it normal that it takes so much time to run? (I have 487 observations)

It's the first time I post a question on this site so please let me know if I should have given other information or if I made any mistake!

Comment: I don't know much about spatial models myself, but have you seen this very thorough guide on spatial models via spaMM or glmmTMB? There is a lot there that is relevant to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can't see any link in your comment but I would be very interested in looking at the guide you are talking about!

Comment: @Erik may have been referring to this:  https://datascienceplus.com/spatial-regression-in-r-part-1-spamm-vs-glmmtmb/

Comment: Thanks, @RobertLong! That's the one.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I read it some time ago but it might be usefull now that I know a little more things about spatial autocorrelation!